# How to extract html links with a matching word from a website using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have an url, say `http://www.bbc.com/news/world/asia/`.  Just in this page I wanted to extract all the links that has India or INDIA or india (should be case insensitive).

If I click any of the output links it should take me to the corresponding page, for example these are few lines that have india  *India shock over Dhoni retirement* and *India fog continues to cause chaos*. If I click these links I should be redirected to `http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30640436` and `http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30630274` respectively.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
url = "http://www.bbc.com/news/world/asia/"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
only_links = SoupStrainer('a', href=re.compile('india'))
print (only_links)
```

I wrote very basic minimal code in python 3.4.2.

Comment: You want all `href` which have a `india` as substring in it. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to search for the word `india` in the *displayed text*. To do this you'll need a custom function instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.bbc.com/news/world/asia/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

india_links = lambda tag: (getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and
                           'href' in tag.attrs and
                           'india' in tag.get_text().lower())
results = soup.find_all(india_links)
```

The `india_links` lambda finds all tags that are `<a>` links with an `href` attribute and contain `india` (case insensitive) somewhere in the displayed text.

Note that I used the `requests` response object *`.content`* attribute; leave decoding to BeautifulSoup!

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://www.bbc.com/news/world/asia/"
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> india_links = lambda tag: getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and 'href' in tag.attrs and 'india' in tag.get_text().lower()
>>> results = soup.find_all(india_links)
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(results)
[<a href="/news/world/asia/india/">India</a>,
 <a class="story" href="/news/world-asia-india-30647504" rel="published-1420102077277">India scheme to monitor toilet use </a>,
 <a class="story" href="/news/world-asia-india-30640444" rel="published-1420022868334">India to scrap tax breaks on cars</a>,
 <a class="story" href="/news/world-asia-india-30640436" rel="published-1420012598505">India shock over Dhoni retirement</a>,
 <a href="/news/world/asia/india/">India</a>,
 <a class="headline-anchor" href="/news/world-asia-india-30630274" rel="published-1419931669523"><img alt="A Delhi police officer with red flag walks amidst morning fog in Delhi, India, Monday, Dec 29, 2014. " src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/79979000/jpg/_79979280_79979240.jpg"/><span class="headline heading-13">India fog continues to cause chaos</span></a>,
 <a class="headline-anchor" href="/news/world-asia-india-30632852" rel="published-1419940599384"><span class="headline heading-13">Court boost to India BJP chief</span></a>,
 <a class="headline-anchor" href="/sport/0/cricket/30632182" rel="published-1419930930045"><span class="headline heading-13">India captain Dhoni quits Tests</span></a>,
 <a class="story" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-radio-and-tv-15386555" rel="published-1392018507550"><img alt="A woman riding a scooter waits for a traffic signal along a street in Mumbai February 5, 2014." src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/72866000/jpg/_72866856_020889093.jpg"/>Special report: India Direct</a>,
 <a href="/2/hi/south_asia/country_profiles/1154019.stm">India</a>]
```

Note the `http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-radio-and-tv-15386555` link here; we had to use the `lambda` search because a search with a `text` regular expression would not have found that element; the contained text (*Special report: India Direct*) is not the only element in the tag and thus would not be found.

A similar problem applies to the `/news/world-asia-india-30632852` link; the nested `<span>` element makes it that the *Court boost to India BJP chief* headline text is not a direct child element of the link tag.

You can extract *just* the links with:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

result_links = [urljoin(url, tag['href']) for tag in results]
```

where all relative URLs are resolved relative to the original URL:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> result_links = [urljoin(url, tag['href']) for tag in results]
>>> pprint(result_links)
['http://www.bbc.com/news/world/asia/india/',
 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30647504',
 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30640444',
 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30640436',
 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world/asia/india/',
 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30630274',
 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30632852',
 'http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/cricket/30632182',
 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-radio-and-tv-15386555',
 'http://www.bbc.com/2/hi/south_asia/country_profiles/1154019.stm']
```

Comment: Hi Martijin, Thanks for help. Iam seeing the results as you mentioned.
How can i do this monitoring periodically say every 1 hour?

Comment: @sandy: that's too broad for comments to answer. There are many ways you can approach that based on your OS and other requirements, including a cron job or windows scheduler job.

Comment: @sandy: post a new question *if you cannot find answers to your specific problems elsewhere*.

Comment: Forgot to upvote, good point about the `text` argument. Thanks.