# How to search multiple words using lambda

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, lambda

I am searching lines that have either `"up"` or `"down"` in the HTML source code. With only one word the code is working. But if I wanted to search lines containing multiple words, how to do it in Python 3.4.2?

```
links = lambda tag: getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and 'up|down' in tag.get_text().lower() and 'href' in tag.attrs
```

Comment: should i provide more info?

Comment: Does your code _have_ to be in a `lambda` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring it has to be inside a function, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730041/how-to-extract-html-links-with-a-matching-word-from-a-website-using-python.

Comment: In that case, Sandy should just use a regular function, rather than trying to stuff the code into a lambda. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make a regular function instead of a short `lambda` form.

Define a list of words you want to check inside the `tag`'s text and use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) + [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) to check for the presence of a word inside the text:

```
stop_words = ['up', 'down']
def filter_links(tag):
    if getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and 'href' in tag.attrs:
        text = tag.get_text().lower()
        return any(item in text for item in stop_words) 
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search` for looking for a list of words

```
lambda tag: (getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and
             re.search("up|down", tag.get_text().lower()) and
             'href' in tag.attrs)
```

Note that however for example `"downsize"` would also match in this case. If you want the separate word `up` or `down` to be present the expression is:

```
re.search("\\b(up|down)\\b", ...)
```

because `\b` means in this context a "word boundary"

Comment: Should be the inverse of it `up` or `down` inside the text.

Comment: @alecxe: `re` module already does caching of compiled expressions internally, I wouldn't uglify the code unless proven inefficient.

Comment: Yup, it does, ok, premature optimizations are evil.