# How I get urls in website that content Apple article only (in python)?

Tags: python, events

I am newer to Python.I want to extract news article that talking about apple.My project want to get articles from BBC website that regarding Apple articles only.My code as follows I crawl the websites.But I can not identify how i get Apple article only.Anyone can help to solve my problem.

code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
#pass the URL
url = urlopen("http://www.bbc.com")
#read the source from the URL
readHtml = url.read()
#close the url
url.close()
#passing HTML to scrap it
soup = BeautifulSoup(readHtml, 'html.parser')
all_tag_a = soup.find_all("a", limit=10)
for links in all_tag_a:
#just pull the href part from each link
 print(links.get('href'))
```

Comment: You could probably use the following api or something similar to get articles related to particular keywords (like Apple) more efficiently than trying to do the requests yourself.
https://newsapi.org/s/bbc-news-api

Comment: @SuryaAvala thank you..I want to crawl the articles given time period.can you explain further.How I change my logic.

Comment: @SuryaAvala I added  `import requests
url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'q=Apple&'
       'from=2018-01-23&'
       'sortBy=popularity&'
       'apiKey=42fd08167d994786b197aa193e26f954')
response = requests.get(url)
print( r.json)      `                                                                                                                                                          In this code what is r.can you explain.I got error like **   print (r.json)
NameError: name 'r' is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:
from urllib.parse import urlparse
o = urlparse('https://www.apple.com/in/') #URL is in the form of-> scheme://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment.
  #whatever URLs your are geeting write it in above statement, may be a loop will help

if 'apple' in o.netloc:
   #If match found then here should be your Apple's URL 
      print o.geturl()
[Please refer this for more onformtaion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: thank you so much your help.your code is helpful but not my expected output.I want to get urls regarding Apple.As an example in BBC website have lot of articles in different section.So I want to get urls regarding Apple.So can you help me.thank you so much

Comment: Then I think you should refer to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730041/how-to-extract-html-links-with-a-matching-word-from-a-website-using-python).

Comment: thank you for your support.That link is helped me.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730041/how-to-extract-html-links-with-a-matching-word-from-a-website-using-python)