# Use OR in Lambda function - Web Scraping Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lambda, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using this example - [How to extract html links with a matching word from a website using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730041/how-to-extract-html-links-with-a-matching-word-from-a-website-using-python)

I wrote a web scraping script to look for keywords in recent and cashed versions of a local newspaper.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = ["https://www.marinij.com/", 'https://web.archive.org/web/20210811185035/https://www.marinij.com/',
        'https://web.archive.org/web/20210506004633/https://www.marinij.com/','https://web.archive.org/web/20210211022431/https://www.marinij.com/',
        'https://web.archive.org/web/20201111174202/https://www.marinij.com/','https://web.archive.org/web/20200811204359/https://www.marinij.com/',
        'https://web.archive.org/web/20200511165943/https://www.marinij.com/','https://web.archive.org/web/20200209014056/https://www.marinij.com/',
        'https://web.archive.org/web/20191111061843/https://www.marinij.com/']

dates = ['today','aug2021','may2021','feb2021','nov2020','aug2020','may2020','feb2020','nov2019']

for i, (url,date) in enumerate(zip(urls,dates)):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    covid_links = lambda tag: (getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and
                            'href' in tag.attrs and
                            ('corona' or 'covid') in tag.get_text().lower())
    
    results = soup.find_all(covid_links)

    num_art = str((len(results)))
    if not results:
        results = ["The term COVID did not appear in the headlines this quarter!\n"]

    textfile = open("marin_covid_" + date + ".txt", "w")
    for idx, element in enumerate(results):
        element = str(element)
        # print(element)
        if idx == 0:
            textfile.write(date + "\n" + "Number of articles = " + num_art + "\n" + "\n" + element + "\n")

        else:
            textfile.write(element + "\n" + "\n")
    textfile.close()

files = ['marin_covid_today.txt', 'marin_covid_aug2021.txt', 'marin_covid_may2021.txt', 'marin_covid_feb2021.txt', 'marin_covid_nov2020.txt',
        'marin_covid_aug2020.txt', 'marin_covid_may2020.txt', 'marin_covid_feb2020.txt']

with open("COVID_articles_in_MIJ.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        with open(filename) as infile:
            contents = infile.read()
            outfile.write(contents)
```

It works really well when using only 1 keyword but when I try using the "or" function to look for 1 or more keyword it is only searching for the 1st word. This can be replicated by switching the 2 keywords in the example - "covid" and "corona".

I know the problem lies in this lambda function but I'm not sure how to address.

```
    covid_links = lambda tag: (getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and
                            'href' in tag.attrs and
                            ('corona' or 'covid') in tag.get_text().lower())
```

This code should be fully executable if you have the prerequisites installed, all help is appreciated.

Comment: The expression `('corona' or 'covid')` evaluates to just `'corona'`, so that's all that's being searched for.  There simply isn't anything you can put on the left side of the `in` operator to search for multiple values; you'd have to write this as `(('corona' in X) or ('covid' in X))`.

Comment: You don't seem to understand order of operations in Python. `('corona' or 'covid')` evaluates to 'corona', so it's then checking if 'corona' is in tag.get_text().lower(). So do `tag.attrs and ('corona' in tag.get_text().lower() or 'covid' in tag.get_text().lower())`

Comment: That's actually very helpful, though you could have been less rude about it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the issue was that 'in' operator must be included either side of the 'or' operator, so that the attribute being evaluated; in this case tag.get_text().lower() can be evaluated for both conditions - "corona" and "covid". The correct lambda function is this:

```
covid_links = lambda tag: (getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and
                            'href' in tag.attrs and
                            ('covid' in tag.get_text().lower() or 'corona' in tag.get_text().lower()))
```